# Django javascript translation catalog file is failing to load, showing error - ReferenceError: gettext is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

As mention in documentation, i have followed below steps -

1. In my settings.py

   ```
   LOCALE_PATHS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
   )

   LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   ugettext = lambda s: s

   LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('mar', ugettext('Marathi')),
   )
   ```
2. My locale directory is in my Django project's root folder
3. In urls.py

   ```
   from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog

   js_info_dict = {
     'packages': ('phone',),
   }  

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^phone/', include('phone.urls')),
       url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict),
   ]
   ```
4. In base.html

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script>
   ```

I am able to see translation done by trans tag, but when m trying to translate variables in javascript using gettext method m getting this particular error

> ReferenceError: gettext is not defined

FYI - djangojs.po and djangojs.mo files are there in my locale directory and i have compiled the file after putting translations on.

I tried hard on google but still same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying hard over a week i got the solution for my problem, which is bit strange for me

i had to re-arrange my url in urls.py as shown below

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict),
 url(r'^phone/', include('phone.urls')),
]
```

as soon as i made above change my JS catalog file got loaded and translation in js file started working.

i did not understand the cause exactly, but would like to share.. might be useful..